# Replacing substrings in a string Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to replace multiple substrings in a string, for example I have the following string `wordlist`

```
one    two    three
```

Where I want to replace `\t` tab characters with `\r\n` new line characters.

I define the `separator` variable as `\n` and `replacement` variable as `\r\n`.

Then I use `wordlist = wordlist.replaceAll(separator, replacement);` to replace all the characters, but when I display the `wordlist` again, it gives me the following result

```
onerntwornthree
```

I also tried splitting the `wordlist` by the substring `separator` into an array and then joining it again word by word into a new string separated by the `replacement`, but then it just gave me a result as

```
one\r\ntwo\r\nthree
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? In case you need it, here's the whole code:

```
System.out.print("Separator to replace: ");
separator = scanner.next( );

System.out.print("Replacement for separator: ");
replacement = scanner.next( );

wordlist = wordlist.replaceAll(separator, replacement);
```

Comment: Show the code you used.

Comment: I explained the whole idea, but if it is relevant, then I edited the post.

Comment: `wordlist.replaceAll("\t", "\r\n")` seems to work just fine: https://ideone.com/sdk1Dt

Comment: @danrodi: you query explicitly for the separator. And then strings are interpreted unescaped...

Answer (score 3):

Your input character for tab seems to be incorrect.

This code gives

```
    String wordlist="one    two three";
    wordlist = wordlist.replaceAll("\t", "\r\n");
    System.out.println(wordlist);
```

This output-

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: This is not portable, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set the separator to `\n`?, it should be `\t` I assume?

The following code works fine for [jdoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/87):

```
String s = "one\ttwo\tthree";
s = s.replaceAll("\t","\r\n");
System.out.println(s);
```

---

**EDIT**

The reason why this doesn't work is because you query the user for the separator and when he enters `\t`, this is a string with the first character `\` and the second `t` and not an escape character.

You should use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava` first.

Thus:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String separator = sc.nextLine();
separator = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(separator);
String s = "one\ttwo\tthree";
s = s.replaceAll(separator,"\r\n");
System.out.println(s);
```

If `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` is not available, you can do this explicitly:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String separator = sc.nextLine();
separator = separator.replaceAll("\\t","\t");
String s = "one\ttwo\tthree";
s = s.replaceAll(separator,"\r\n");
System.out.println(s);
```

[demo](http://jdoodle.com/a/87)

Comment: I tried the second option without the StringEscapeUtils, but it still keeps giving me the same result. Note that the replacement is also asked from the user and the separator doesn't have to be \t necessarily, it could also be \n.

Comment: Well, how do you enter the replacement? With *tabs* or with (explicit) `"\t"`?

Comment: If using the example I explained my problem with, when asked for separator I type in \t and press Enter, then I'm asked for replacement where I type in \r\n and press Enter again.

Comment: You need to perform two `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava` (on both separator and replacement)...

Comment: Used `separator = separator.replaceAll("\\t","\t");` and `replacement = replacement.replaceAll("\\r\n","\r\n");`, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is probably to split the string and the write the different lines one at a time to a PrintStream. That way you can use println.

Java is a platform independent language, and new lines are platform dependent. Making use of PrintStream.println will make sure your code is portable.